# Using abstract class in template for generic class based DetailView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I just started working with generic class based views and love it. I do have one struggle that I still can't solve.

I have one abstract class called group, and two childs Company and Bond. (I simplified my example). This is my models.py:

**models.py**

```
class Group(BaseModel):                                                         
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)                                                

    class Meta:                                                                    
        abstract = True                                                            


class Company(Group):                                                              
    def __str__(self):                                                             
        return "Company " + self.name                                              


class Bond(Group):                                                                 
    def __str__(self):                                                             
        return "Bond " + self.name
```

Now when displaying one of my objects with the generic class based detail view, I want to have one group_detail.html template, and call group.name. This doesn't work however, I need to call company.name or bond.name, depending on the object type. Since my original model has a lot more attributes, this is undesirable because it results in a lot of duplicate code. Do you guys know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group` has no instances in the database as it's an abstract class so you can't query it. You have to query `Company` or `Bond` and so pass `Company` or `Bond` objects to a template.

If your `Company` and `Bond` models have the same attributes you can pass their object to a template with a single context name, this will let you use one template. But, actually, I think your `Company` and `Bond` models are different so you can't create one template for both of them, they will differ, so there is no code duplication at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same template for both views, and use the automatically passed `object` variable to the context, like `{{ object.name }}`.